# Inkscape - Mapping the transform scale onto the path of SVG

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, path, transform

I have this big vector (SVG) graphic which is not to scale. I want to scale it to size. However, doing so in Inkscape applies transform-scale on the paths parent `group`. What I want is for the path values to be updated instead of the scale being applied to the whole `group`.

As an example, the element has values as such:

```
`M240,399.1c0,221.3,179.6,399.1,399.1,399.1s399.1-177.8,399.1-399.1S860.4,0,639.1,0  S240,179.6,240,399.1`
```

However, if this same path was 'to scale', it would probably be something similar to below:

```
M2.321,6.432 c0,0.231,1.021....etc
```

So, how can I scale the vector graphic in Inkscape so that the transformation is applied to the individual paths instead of the parent group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break paths out of a group in order to work with them individually. The menu option is Path->Break Apart. The shortcut is `Shift-Ctrl-k`

When you're done, you can re-group them (Path->Combine or `Ctrl-k`)

Comment: Thank you, I believe, that did it. I had to 'break apart' the group then scale them, then re-group.